# Spawn an xml model in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, xml, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my xml file(name:pool.xml):

Gazebo/White

I used the command line:
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file pwd/pool.xml -urdf -z 1 -model my_pool

I have the master node running(empty_world.launch), but after the command line nothing appears. How can I spawn the current xml file (if everything is ok with it) in an empty_world.launch??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12737/spawn-an-xml-model-in-gazebo/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you actually use the pwd/pool.xml? If yes pwd is supposed to be the directory where you saved pool.xml like ros/electric/stack/Tutorial/pool_package/.

---

Originally posted by [OptiX](https://answers.ros.org/users/1535/optix/) with karma: 63 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0